# Microsoft Office alternative for Windows?

Tags: windows, microsoft-office

Is there something similar to Office for Windows but free? I am student living on a budget, Office is not an option at the moment.

Comment: Doesn't your university/college offer cheap student licenses?

Comment: unfortunately no I am from India but they are trying to cooperate with microsoft lately to help students so maybe in future I hope

Comment: You could always just use Google Docs or Zoho.com to get an online word processor ;-)

Comment: I'm fascinated by the prices quoted in various answers for student editions. MS has made their pricing structure so complicated, no one can figure out what anything costs...

Answer (score 114, accepted):

Try [OpenOffice.org](http://www.openoffice.org/)

**Edit**: Since the creation of this post, many if not most of the supporters of OpenOffice.org have migrated to **[LibreOffice](http://www.libreoffice.org/)**, which was originally based on OpenOffice.org and now has a more active development than its parent project.

Comment: Great program. Easy to use. Just like microsoft, but without macros, so you elimintate some of the viruses you can get

Comment: @Dynamic - You can write macros for OOo, it even has a VBA compliance mode to let it run some (but not all) macros designed for MS Office.

Comment: This answer has a lot of traction. I wonder if in the interim period you have switched to LibreOffice? With the pace of development better handling of MS formats if you have switched, maybe you should edit the answer. (and I agree with the usefulness, it's all I've used for work, school, and at home for 2 years)

Answer (score 26):

There are a number of web-based Office services that are also free and offer some of the functionality of Microsoft Office, including:

[Office Web Apps](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/web-apps/)

[Google Docs](http://docs.google.com/)

Zoho Office

While these tend to lack the more advanced features of client-side Office suites, they do have excellent collaboration features.

Comment: Anyone else thinks this might actually become the top answer in about 2-3 years time?

Comment: Over two years later, still not the top answer.  We'll see what the next year brings us.

Answer (score 10):

Search for your school through the [MSDN Academic Alliance](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/academic/dd861347.aspx). Even if it's not free, it will be significantly cheaper (to the tune of $30 or less).

Comment: I have this through school and I love it! Unfortunately office isn't included :( Mostly Different versions of Windows and programs like Visual Studio and Virtual PC.

Comment: Office products tend to not be included in the MSDN academic alliance in most places I have seen.

Answer (score 10):

You didn't specify if you need MS-Office interoperability.

[AbiWord](http://www.abisource.com/) for word processing has [some](http://www.abisource.com/wiki/Microsoft_Word_documents) interoperability with MS-Word, and seems popular for people who find OpenOffice too cumbersome.

For spreadsheets, there's also [Gnumeric](http://projects.gnome.org/gnumeric/) although they seem to be a bit unsure as to the stability of the windows build.

I use [OpenOffice](http://www.openoffice.org/) personally, which does a pretty good job overall, including easy production of PDFs, and MS-Office interoperability as far as Word and Excel goes.

And of course, there's [Google Docs](http://docs.google.com/) that others have mentioned.

Answer (score 10):

[Libre Office](http://www.libreoffice.org/) is another new kid on the block, created by former OpenOffice.org developers 
who left following the Oracle buyout of Sun. It's fairly new but releases seem to be coming thick and fast!

Answer (score 5):

I know it's not free, but you can get Office 2007 Ultimate for $60 if you are a student. All you need is a .edu email address. Just go to [www.ultimatesteal.com](http://www.ultimatesteal.com).

It looks like that program is just for the US, but they have similar programs in the [UK](http://www.theultimatesteal.co.uk) and [Canada](http://www.theultimatesteal.ca/).

Thanks to Gnoupi, here is the [French version](http://student.officepourlesetudiants.fr/).

Comment: why do i have to be from US?

Comment: can they send to other countries?

Comment: I found versions for the UK and Canada.

Comment: French version : http://student.officepourlesetudiants.fr/

Comment: if you can find india version that will be great...

Comment: Unfortunately, it does not appear to be a program that is valid in India. I suggest trying open office until you can get a cheap version of office.

Comment: @Gnoupi: Link appears to be dead.

Answer (score 3):

If your school does not offer a cheap education version of office, Microsoft does make a $70 home and student edition if you need maximum compatibility.

[http://www.amazon.com/Microsoft-Office-Home-Student-2007/dp/B000HCZ8EO](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B000HCZ8EO)

EDIT: Newegg mentions a 3 user licence. So maybe you can get 3 people to go in on one.

http://www.newegg.com/Product/Product.aspx?Item=N82E16832116135

Comment: Please verify, but I believe the Office Home and Student has a 3-user license, so perhaps you could get 2 of your classmates to chip in with you?

Answer (score 2):

You might check out [Lotus Symphony](http://symphony.lotus.com/software/lotus/symphony/home.nsf/home).

Answer (score 2):

Another alternative not yet mentioned is LaTeX. It is not a wysiwyg editor like Word or Libreoffice, but it is specifically geared for publication quality typesetting, and especially useful for academic work. It has specific abilities to typeset math, and also has tools to work with a bibliographic database and automatically format your references and footnotes.

There are several free/open-source distributions, includeing [mikTeX](http://miktex.org/), and [TeXLive](http://www.tug.org/texlive/).

Support websites include [TeX.stackexchange.com](http://tex.stackexchange.com) and [Latex-Community.org](http://www.latex-community.org/).

Examples of thesis templates exist [here](http://openwetware.org/wiki/LaTeX_template_for_PhD_thesis) and on [GitHub](https://github.com/FlorianX/Latex-Template-Thesis).

A good starting point for learning LaTeX is the [wikibook](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX).

See also the stackoverflow discussion [is LaTeX worth learning today?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/874576/is-latex-worth-learning-today)

Answer (score 1):

You may also want to try the [Google office](http://docs.google.com) products: Google Docs, Google Spreadsheets and Google Presentation. Over the last year they have added a lot of features, such that now they are pretty close to what you'd find in a offie suite, minus the fancy features you'd never use. They also export quite nicely to Microsoft Office and other formats when you need to and you don't have to worry about loosing your work when your computer crashes or the program/browser crashes (they save automatically, almost too automatic).

Another option/new commer is [Office Live](http://workspace.office.live.com)--Microsoft's answer to Google Docs, etc. It has some nice features that Google Docs doesn't have, but is also free...so you can use both :)

Here is a comparison between the 2: http://www.pcworld.com/article/168309/microsoft_office_vsgoogle_docs_a_web_apps_showdown.html There are ofcourse many other comparisons out there.

**Edit** Another possibility is [OpenGoo](http://www.opengoo.org/). It's an open source solution that you can install on your own server and manage yourself.

Comment: Define "pretty close."

Comment: Just took a look at right now, and I really can't see anything that I would use in Word that is missing in Google Docs, but for example, they only have 11 fonts. But something like this, I don't see being problem unless your trying to make something "fancy".

Answer (score 0):

[ThinkFree](http://thinkfree.com/) is actually a well executed Java clone of Office, and its free.

There was another one that did PowerPoint only, and did it really well, but I can't remember the name of it now

Answer (score -1):

[SoftMaker Office 2010](http://www.softmaker.com/english/of_en.htm) for example. Perfect alternative, cheap, **fast**, lightweight.