# Any alternative to Microsoft Office?

Tags: microsoft-office

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Microsoft Office alternative for Windows?](https://superuser.com/questions/21228/microsoft-office-alternative-for-windows)

Any alternative to Microsoft Office? Because it is not free. I need a free office application.

Comment: Please check your e-mail. You have been sent two warnings with regards to questions that has been deleted.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

[OpenOffice.org](http://www.openoffice.org/) is a free office suite and a very good one. It is cross-platform as well.

Answer (score 2):

[Google Docs](http://www.google.com/google-d-s/tour1.html) is worth a look.  Has the added benefit of being a bit more accessible if you want to work with your documents without installing software.

Not as feature packed as Open Office or Microsoft Office admittedly.