# Microsoft Office Alternatives

Tags: windows-7, microsoft-word, google-drive

I have a windows 7 computer with no Microsoft Office installed on it. Occasionally I have to view and print some documents created in Microsoft Office. I also have to sometimes create documents. I used Google docs before but it is not very reliable and some .doxc files look weird in Google docs. How can I view,print and create,edit word documents, so that they could be compatible with the actual Microsoft Office Word.

Comment: Check out OpenOffice/LibreOffice.

Comment: We are unable to do product recomendations.  If you did a google search you woudl find lots of choices.  **You get what you paid for in most cases.**

Comment: not asking for a product recommendation, this question will yield a constructive answer.

Comment: So, how will you choose a correct answer if you ask for alternatives? Every question proposing some alternative will be correct. This question is primarily opinion based and is a product recommendation question. http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/11/qa-is-hard-lets-go-shopping/

Comment: @gronostaj well an answer can include multiple alternatives.

Comment: Please define a product recommendation question in such a way that "[X] alternatives" questions aren't product recommendation questions.

Comment: @JebediahKerman - Which would make the answer a product recomendation. There isn't any possible modification to this question where it would become helpful.  Besides its been asked and answered before http://superuser.com/questions/21228/microsoft-office-alternative-for-windows

Comment: The title of the post says you want a definitive list of MS Office alternative products, which can produce a factual answer. Your content body asks for recommendations based on specific criteria, which will produce opinionated answers.

Comment: file a support ticket to google support and they will fixed the weird things for you, but, this is not free. you need $5 per month for the support service.  http://www.google.com/enterprise/apps/business/pricing.html

Comment: Have you checked out [Office Web Apps](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/web-apps)?

Comment: Perhaps this question would be more useful if it were revised to be more specific in what type of document is being used.  In @Jebediah Kerman's question he stated "I have to view and print some documents".  What type of documents? Essays?  Statistical reports? Computer Log? Etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OpenOffice/GoogleDocs are probably the top choice for creating/editing but if you absolutely need it to look right when viewing only then Microsoft provides a free viewer.

http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=4

Comment: Not sure who downvoted but OP's question has the following things: (1) A problem [view Office docs without paying for MS Office] (2) An attempt [tried google Docs but some docs look funny] (3) A question/request with a finite answer [How to create/view/print/edit with MS Office compatibility?]...With that said, had OP simply said `Give me a free way to create/edit/view Word docs` then I would have certainly downvoted the question.

Comment: @Ramhound that question doesn't have the three things that I pointed out, of course it was closed. OP put forth an effort but wasn't aware of ALL technologies. Can you faithfully say OP doesn't want to learn?

Comment: @Ramhound so changing the title to `Google Docs unreliable .docx interpretation` and then asking how to fix it in the body would resolve the issue?

Answer (score 1):

There is no 1:1 alternative. You will need to tweak/verify formatting whenever you export/import files between different viewers.

I have had a lot of success using Google Drive to import and export word docs but even so you need to check it over. Open Office is another alternative which you will still need to check over.

If you want to maintain the same reliable format you need to stick with MS Office.

You might also try using .doc instead of .docx, and .xls instead of .xlsx for compatability.

Comment: well what is the closest thing an alternative.

Comment: Both GD and OO have their own individual quirks with format conversions so it is up to your preference.